# How to divide code fragments in shiny using buttons?

Tags: r, shiny

Can i divide code fragments in shiny using buttons?
To be more clear I am working on an app that produces plots as per the buttons "YTD","Last Month","Current Month","7 Days" 
when suppose Last month is selected it produces a plot of data from the last month( with respect to system date) upto the system date
so what do i write in server.r so that with click in buttons my plot changes?

Comment: What you already try? and better show some example which we can easy reproduce.

Comment: Maybe try to read this tutorial step by step before you begin: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/

Comment: What i did is that i gave an if condition


 count<-0
      if(input$ytd!=0 & count%%4==0)
    {
    y<-year(t)
    st<-"01-01"
    y<-paste(y,st,sep="-")
    u<-as.Date(y)
    v<-as.yearmon(y)
    count<-count+1
    }
      if(input$lm!=0 & count%%4==1){
       u<-t-30
       count<-count+1
         }
      if(input$cm!=0 & count%%4==2)
        {u<-t-mday(t)+1
        count<-count+1
      }
      if(input$sd!=0 & count%%4==3)
      {u<-t-7
      count<-count+1
}

it works fine if i click the buttons in sequence "YTD","Last month","Current Month","7 days"

Comment: Could you edit your question (with this comment) to make it readible?

Comment: Add some code to the question.